# Changing content dynamically inside react-native-pager-view (or any other)

Tags: javascript, react-native

i'm working on a project where i'm going to be displaying details and information about a certain book page by page inside a pager view as page components, the book contains 500+ pages so i can't just create 500 page components like that and insert them into the pager..what i thought is i can get a specific page, render its component, alongside the previous, and the next page only..and when the user swipes to the next/previous page i would change the component state, and have it re-render with the new 3 pages, the current one, the previous, and the next one. the logic in my head makes perfect sense, but it just won't work when i try to apply it.

can anyone help me, guide me to certain videos that explain this principal more? i feel like i'm missing something.

the code goes like this:

first i have the PagesContainer, here i will create the PagesDetails component(s) based on the current page, and having these pages in react-native-pager-view (you can suggest me a better option). for testing purpose only, i set the swipe end callback (onPageSelected) to increment the current page number state, which would then cause the component to re-render and create the new page component(s), that happens only when the user swipes to new page of course:

```
function PagesContainer({ currentPageNumber, setCurrentPageNumber }) {
    const [pageComponents, setPageComponents] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        let compArr = [];
        compArr.push(<PageDetails key="current" pageNumber={currentPageNumber} />);
        if (currentPageNumber > 1) {
            compArr.unshift(<PageDetails key="previous" pageNumber={currentPageNumber - 1} />)
        }
        if (currentPageNumber <= 500) {
            compArr.push(<PageDetails key="next" pageNumber={currentPageNumber + 1} />)
        }
        setPageComponents(compArr);
    }, [currentPageNumber])

    return (<PagerView style={{ flex: 1 }} 
    initialPage={currentPageNumber == 1 ? 0 : 1}
    layoutDirection={"rtl"}
    onPageSelected={(PageSelectedEvent)=>{setCurrentPageNumber(currentPageNumber + 1)}}
    >
        {pageComponents.map(page => {
            return page;
        })}
    </PagerView>)
}
```

and then here i have my PageDeatails component where i simply display texts and details of the page, i take the data from the bookData object which is imported at the very top of the code file:

```
function PageDetails({ pageNumber }) {
    const [pageContent, setPageContent] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        setPageContent(bookData[pageNumber]["pageContent"]);
    }, []);
        return (
        <View>
            {pageContent && <View>
                {pageContent.map(item => {
                    return (<Text>item</Text>)
                })}
            </View>
            }
        </View>
    )
}
```

The logic makes perfect sense in my head but it just doesn't work when i test it..what am i missing? what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you log `pageContent` and post the output?

Answer (score 0):

use the PagerView reference using **useRef** also store the page index and pass to  **initialPage** get current page index from **onPageSelected** callback

like:

```
initialPage={currentPageIndex}
```

Comment: Need to change the pages not just the intialpage

Comment: I try this but unfortunately, the page can't rerender the screen.
So, that's why I use initialPage.

Answer (score 0):

Use ref by passing PagerView ref to PagerView:

```
import PagerView from "react-native-pager-view";
import React from "react"

const Slider = () => {
const [page, setPage] = React.useState(0)
const ref = React.createRef<PagerView>()

const handleChangePage = () => {
     ref.current?setPage(page+1)
}

return (
<View>
   <PagerView initialPage={page} ref={ref} onPageSelected={(e)=> setPage(e.nativeEvent.position)}>
     <Slide1 />
     <Slide1 />
     <Slide1 />
   </PagerView>
   <Button title="Next" onPress={handleChangePage}>
</View>
)
}
```