# Force react-native-pager-view to rerender

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm looking for a way to force the pager view to re-render, i'm trying to dynamically change the content of the pagerview component when the state changes, i'm logging the states and i can see that the contents of the state are actually changing but i'm not seeing any changes happen on the app itself..i think i need to force the pager to re-render so that it shows the newly created components..i'm looking for something similar to flatlist's "extraData" prop.

my code and original question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74734956/changing-content-dynamically-inside-react-native-pager-view-or-any-other)