# react-native-pager-view prevent onPageSelected from running on render

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm working on a react-native project and i'm looking for a way to execute a function when the user swipes between pages contained inside react-native-pager-view, what [react-native-pager-view](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pager-view) provides is the "onPageSelected" callback which runs when swiping alright but it also runs on initial render and on any other re-render which is breaking my code's logic and all state changes of the app. i need a way to prevent the onPageSelected from running on renders or another equivalent callback, something like onSwipeEnd which is provided by other packages.

is there such a thing?

my original code and original issue can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74734956/changing-content-dynamically-inside-react-native-pager-view-or-any-other)